# Kde custom resolution

Tags: linux, xorg, kde, display-settings, kde-plasma-5

Everything is just a tad too small on Kde plasma 5 on my 1080p laptop. Everything looks peefect when I force 1600x900 using xrandr but a logout removes this setting and kscreen does not give it as an option.  What can I do?

Comment: Is your preference a permanent setting to a reduced resolution or a way to enlarge specific problem elements (default font, system tray icon height, icons in general, etc.)?

Comment: I'd like a permanent reduction for the laptop screen but not for external screens

Comment: Seems like a bug to mee. xrandr repors resolutions kscreen doesn't offer to set.

Comment: @JohnDoe it's not a standard xrandr resolution, I have to create it and it disappears after a reboot.